# Occassionally Extremely Slow PHP Echo Statements

Tags: php, performance

99%+ of my Server requests are served in less then 30ms.  Using New Relic, I've discovered that occassionally, I get requests that take 3 to 30 seconds, almost 1000 times longer then average!  In every case that I've investigated, New relic shows that 99%+ of the execution time is in the echo statement which consists of:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
exit;
```

The above code is used by all my requests and works just fine 99.99% of the time (Server gets 100K requests/hour, but about less then 20 of those exhibit the slow behaviour). 
Newrelic shows server resources in 1 minute increments.  I've already checked: CPU, Memory usage, Disk I/O, Network I/O, and Load Average.  They all appear normal before, durring, and after the times of the long requests.

I found this post:
http://www.wonko.com/post/seeing_poor_performance_using_phps_echo_statement_heres_why

Even after applying the echoBig function with standard buffering size, It's still slow.
My phpinfo() shows that output_buffering = 4096

Any ideas on this?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with your code shown.  I'm curious though, what's in `$json`?  Is there is typical size?  Do you see a spike in time above a certain size?  Can your server only handle one PHP instance at once for some reason?  There are a lot of variables here...  Can you try to make this happen in a predictable way?  Load testing perhaps?

Comment: That's tough. How do you run PHP? (Apache mod_php/fastcgi/php-fpm/..) how does new relic measure the time?

Comment: $json is a string of characters created from json_encode( $phpObject ).  The typical size of the response is anywhere from 1kb to 40 kb (after gzipping), but the response size usually doesn't exceed 100Kb (after gzip).  Unfortunately I can't measure the size using newrelic, so I'll have to create my own logging for that.

Comment: Are there any server settings that may affect this?